# drag and drop a group of cells in jGraphX graph editor

Tags: java, jgraphx

I am using jGraphX for my application.
  In jgraphX graph editor program drag and drop of icon from editor palette, it inserts single cell to the graph component.
eg. If I drag and dropped square icon it inserts square cell in graph

But I need to insert a group of cell to the graph component
eg.If i drag and dropped group icon it insert the group cell.
  group cell contains two square(vertex) cell connected to each other(edge)

I have tried it by creating the new template in the editor palette

```
mxCell cell=  new mxCell(.......);
mxCell cell1=new mxCell(....);
cell.setTarget(cell);
```

but it inserts only one cell. Help me to insert a group of cell in the graph by drag and drop

Answer (score 0):

I have sucessfully done it by adding code(graph.insertVertex & graph.insertEdge) inside the mouse drag event function.